# WordPress - Unable to Login

Tags: wordpress

I was updating WP and working inside jut fine, then all of a sudden can't login or see anything. This is what I'm getting: [twitter] error: PHP 5.3.0 or later requires

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-login.php on line 415

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-login.php on line 427

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 678

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 679

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 680

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/keread/public_html/wp-content/plugins/twitter/widget_twitter_vjck.php:77) in /home2/keread/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `twitter` plugin?

Comment: Unsure how to, will try to do what the two other kind people suggested. A total noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that Twitter plugin was completely re-written last July and none of the previous versions are available anymore. But, versions 2.0 and 2.0.1 of the Twitter plugin require PHP 5.3 or higher, which you don't seem to be running.

I'd recommend renaming the Twitter plugin's directory to something else so WordPress can't find it anymore and deactivates the plugin. That should make it so you can log in again. From there, your options are to get PHP upgraded on your server (probably the responsibility of your hosting provider) or find a different Twitter plugin.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! Sincerely appreciate!!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like one of your plugins is throwing a bit of a tantrum.

If you can access your database, I'd recommend de-activating all the plugins by dropping the row in `wp_options` with the `option_name`: `active_plugins`.

Additional reading [here](http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/), if you need it!

Edit: the quick solution, from the linked post:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

Comment: While links may guide the OP to a solution, it may not be helpful towards future visitors (ie. link goes dead). Please post the relevant excerpt from the provided link *into* your answer.

Comment: The relevant info is in the answer. Nonetheless, I've pasted a nice little query from the post. Thanks for the advice!